# Confusion about ordering in output of PageRankCentrality

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm doing a project in which I want to rank the nodes of a graph using page-rank centrality. The Mathematica documentation for `PageRankCentrality` is:

> `PageRankCentrality[g, α]`, gives a list of page-rank centralities for the vertices in the graph `g` and weight `α`.

For example, it may return something like: `{0.04, 0.0012, 0.093}`, where each element of the list is a centrality measure. My question is how do I figure out which nodes each of these centrality measures represents? In other words, how would I figure out if node 1, 2, or 3 is the node that corresponds to `0.04`, `0.0012`, or `0.093`?

Thank you so much!

Comment: They are ordered by VertexIndex, i.e., 1, 2, 3, ...

Answer (score 2):

All functions that returns values that characterize vertices return them in the same order as `VertexList`.

If you want to get an association between vertices and centralities, you could use something similar to

```
g = Graph[{2 <-> 1, 3 <-> 2}];

AssociationThread[
 VertexList[g],
 BetweennessCentrality[g]
 ]
```

As you can see here, the vertex *names* (which happen to be integers here) are not the same as the vertex *indices*, i.e. the position of vertices in `VertexList`.